# Bates and Sierra java scjp chapter 2 has-a

Tags: java

```
public class Horse extends Animal {
    private Halter myHalter = new Halter();
    public void tie(LeadRope rope) {
        myHalter.tie(rope); // Delegate tie behavior to the
        // Halter object
    }
}
public class Halter {
    public void tie(LeadRope aRope) {
        // Do the actual tie work here
    }
}
```

Is the tie method in Horse class overriding the tie method in the Halter class? Why is the tie method declaration and signature almost exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not overriding the method in Halter, because Horse does not extend Halter.

This is an example of a delegate (as mentioned in the comment). Maybe also of the Facade pattern (put all horse-business in one place, even though it could be done by going through all the other classes directly).

This is the difference between IS-A and HAS-A relationships. A horse has a halter (but it is no halter).

> Why is the tie method declaration and signature almost exactly the same?

Because they do the same thing: Tie the receiver to the lead rope.

As it happens, you can tie both halters and horses to ropes. But in other aspects they are quite different animals (only one of them is, in fact, an animal).

Some people will argue that this could be abstracted away in a `Tieable` interface. Then calling code could tie lead ropes to both horses and halters (and possibly other things), without needing to know about either.

Comment: So, does tie get put into a wrapper method because of the absence of the main method? That's the only reason I can think of that it would have to be wrapped. Thanks, these answers have really helped.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "main method" (or "wrapper method" for that matter). I think the idea here is that the Horse provides the interface for client code, and Halter does the actual work related to tying ropes.

Comment: You don't know what I mean by "main method?" Really?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not overriding the `tie` method as you see `Horse` doesn't extend `Halter` class.

The method name is kept same so that you can call the `Halter` class `tie` method from an instance of `Horse` class with the same name.

It just wraps the method call to `tie` method of `Halter` class inside a method (which has same signature) from `Horse` class.

Comment: So they are two different methods with the same signature? I've never seen an example of this nature so it confused me.

Comment: yes they are two different method with same signature but the inheritance relationship is not there between the two classes they there is no overriding.